# Does Ktor Provide any Inbuilt Database

Tags: android, database, kotlin, ktor, ktor-client

I'm very much new to **Ktor**. I'm totally confused that **does Ktor provides any inbuilt database and any interface** where we can actually see our data in **tabular form** (Like in MySQL) or like as in Firebase Database (In Colection-Documents Form).

I want to build an Android Application that will require an database.

As an API i am trying to use Ktor. I have watched some of the tutorials for basics of it and all of them uses an **variable** to store all the data and then refer them.

For Example -

```
val rabbits = listOf(
Rabbit("Carl", "A cute brown rabbit", "$BASE_URL/rabbits/rabbit1.jpg"),
Rabbit("Emma", "Emma likes to eat apples", "$BASE_URL/rabbits/rabbit2.jpg"),
)
```

Please Tell me if there is an inbuilt database for Ktor if not what is the best database that Ktor supports the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ktor is only a web client -- it doesn't store data in the way you're thinking. For Kotlin on Android, as long as your data is relatively small and simple, regular lists/maps should suffice. More complex and large-volume data will need in-memory databases, persistent storage on the device, or more, but in most use-cases, this isn't needed.